# How to take array of foreign keys in django model

Tags: django

I have a model product , price and custorder. I want a list of products while creating the order which is used as a foreign key in custorder. I am using postgres as database.

```
class Product(models.Model):

    product = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=200), blank=True)

    def __str__(self):

         return str(self.product)

class Price(models.Model):

    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places = 5, default=0)

    def __str__(self):

        return "%s" % self.price

class CustOrder(models.Model):

    Customer_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    CustomerName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70,blank=True, null= True, unique= True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    phone = PhoneField(null=False, blank=True, unique=True)
    landmark = models.PointField()
    #landmark = models.TextField(max_length=400, help_text="Enter the landmark", default='Enter landmark')
    houseno = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    #product_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=PRODUCT_CHOICES,default='Boneless chicken')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='pricetag')
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,related_name='pricetag')
    #price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=5, default=48.9)
    pay_method = models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=PAYMENT_CHOICES, default='RAZOR PAY')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True) 
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    Price.objects.aggregate(Sum('price'))
    def __str__(self):
         return self.CustomerName
```

Comment: Your question isn't much clear

Comment: I want that while creating order for customer .. he should be able to order multiple products so for that i have used array field in product class but what should i use in custorder.product to show that array of product

Comment: I guess you have to make `custorder.product` a ManyToMany relationship, since a order can contain many products

Comment: I have used it like:   product = models.ManyToManyField (Product)     But still it's not working

Comment: can you add the view where you are trying to add the data to the question, I guess that would make it more clear

Comment: Actually it got solved i just used an intermediate model here

Comment: Cool @neha, if you are building an ecommerce store I would suggest using an ecommerce framework Django Oscar, you can look at their docs here: (http://oscarcommerce.com/) and (https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/)

Comment: class CustOrderViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CustOrder.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    serializer_class = CustOrderSerializer

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.AllowAny
    ]
    
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

Comment: This is my view set for cust order and products

Comment: Actually the problem still persist